# Why background-color:white; doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}

span{
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

div{
  border-top: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<span>test</span>
<div></div>
```

As you see, that black line is still on the text. While I've set a white background color to the text. Why it doesn't appear?

I want to cut that black line on the text's edges. In other word, that line should be surround the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `span` need position, i.e. `position: relative` for `z-index` to work

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}

span{
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

div{
  border-top: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<span>test</span>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative`to the span.

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}

span{
  position:relative;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

div{
  border-top: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<span>test</span>
<div></div>
```

Comment: That solution was given already 10 min. ago ... so why one more? ... and a good answer should also have an explanation _why_ it works

Answer (score -1):

Where is your Body TAG ?

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}

span{
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
}

div{
  border-top: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <span>test</span>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The tags `html`, `head` and `body` is added automatic for snippets, so no need to add explicit, still, how does this answer the question? ... the _black line_ is still on top of the text

Comment: Anybody noticed the Run code snippet is inside the code block? Why?

Comment: Hey Man See The Body in code snippet, see the background color is wrap content of span.
you know its your answer?